# How to call a shell script from python code?

Tags: python, shell

How to call a shell script from python code?

Answer (score 372, accepted):

The [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module will help you out.

Blatantly trivial example:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.call(['sh', './test.sh']) # Thanks @Jim Dennis for suggesting the []
0 
>>>
```

Where `test.sh` is a simple shell script and `0` is its return value for this run.

Comment: Note: it's preferable to pass subprocess.call() a list rather than a string (see command to Hugo24 below for the example and reasons).

Comment: The link to the tutorial is broken.

Comment: This gives: OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied. my script does not required to run with sudo. @Manoj Govindan

Comment: With arguments: subprocess.call(['./test.sh', 'param1', 'param2'])

Comment: @alper go the folder where you have placed the script and run the command,  `chmod +x script.sh`. Note: script.sh is a placeholder for your script, replace it accordingly.

Comment: The subprocess api has changed in python 3.5. The new method is .run(args) instead of call

Comment: I believe you need to add `subprocess.call(['sh', './test.sh'])`
Otherwise it raises exec format error as discussed in here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26807937/subprocess-popen-oserror-errno-8-exec-format-error-in-python

Comment: Otherwise we are assuming that `test.sh` always starts with the shebang specifying which interpreter to use. Better to do it in Python imo. Explicit over implicit.

Answer (score 138):

There are some ways using `os.popen()` (deprecated) or the whole `subprocess` module, but [this approach](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/os.html#os.system)

```py
import os
os.system(command)
```

is one of the easiest.

Comment: why isn't this the most upvoted answer? Isn't not having to import a module the better solution? Must be some drawback here?

Comment: With `subprocess` you can manage input/output/error pipes. It is also better when you have many arguments -- with `os.command()` you will have to create whole command line with escaping special characters, with `subprocess` there is simple list of arguments. But for simple tasks `os.command()`  may be just sufficient.

Comment: To quote from that link: `The subprocess module provides more powerful facilities for spawning new processes and retrieving their results; *using that module is preferable to using this function.*`

Answer (score 58):

In case you want to pass some parameters to your shell script, you can use the method [shlex.split()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shlex.html#shlex.split):

```
import subprocess
import shlex
subprocess.call(shlex.split('./test.sh param1 param2'))
```

with `test.sh` in the same folder:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo $1
echo $2
exit 0
```

Outputs:

```
$ python test.py 
param1
param2
```

Comment: This is elegant.

Comment: How to pass python variable as an argument ?

Comment: @keerthi007 `subprocess.call(shlex.split(f"./test.sh param1 {your_python_var} param3"))`

Answer (score 31):

```
import os
import sys
```

Assuming test.sh is the shell script that you would want to execute

```
os.system("sh test.sh")
```

Answer (score 19):

Use the subprocess module as mentioned above.

I use it like this:

```
subprocess.call(["notepad"])
```

Comment: Note: calling subprocess with a list is safer since it doesn't necessitate passing the (potentially unsanitized) string through a shell for parsing/interpretation. The first item in the list will be the executable and all other items will be passed as arguments.

Answer (score 19):

I'm running python 3.5 and subprocess.call(['./test.sh']) doesn't work for me.

I give you three solutions depends on what you wanna do with the output.

1 - call script. You will see output in your terminal. output is a number.

```
import subprocess 
output = subprocess.call(['test.sh'])
```

2 - call and dump execution and error into string. You don't see execution in your terminal unless you print(stdout). Shell=True as argument in Popen doesn't work for me.

```
import subprocess
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

session = subprocess.Popen(['test.sh'], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
stdout, stderr = session.communicate()

if stderr:
    raise Exception("Error "+str(stderr))
```

3 - call script and dump the echo commands of temp.txt in temp_file

```
import subprocess
temp_file = open("temp.txt",'w')
subprocess.call([executable], stdout=temp_file)
with open("temp.txt",'r') as file:
    output = file.read()
print(output)
```

Don't forget to take a look at the [doc subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess)

Comment: **Note**

Do not use stdout=PIPE or stderr=PIPE with ```subprocess.call```. The child process will block if it generates enough output to a pipe to fill up the OS pipe buffer as the pipes are not being read from.

Answer (score 14):

I know this is an old question but I stumbled upon this recently and it ended up misguiding me since the [Subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#call-function-trio) API as changed since python 3.5.

The new way to execute external scripts is with the `run` function, which runs the command described by args. Waits for command to complete, then returns a CompletedProcess instance.

```
import subprocess

subprocess.run(['./test.sh'])
```

Answer (score 8):

In case the script is having multiple arguments

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import subprocess
output = subprocess.call(["./test.sh","xyz","1234"])
print output
```

Output will give the status code. If script runs successfully it will give 0 otherwise non-zero integer.

```
podname=xyz  serial=1234
0
```

Below is the test.sh shell script.

```
#!/bin/bash

podname=$1
serial=$2
echo "podname=$podname  serial=$serial"
```

Answer (score 4):

Subprocess module is a good module to launch subprocesses.
You can use it to call shell commands as this:

```
subprocess.call(["ls","-l"]);
#basic syntax
#subprocess.call(args, *)
```

You can see its documentation [here.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess)

If you have your script written in some .sh file or a long string, then you can use os.system module. It is fairly simple and easy to call:

```
import os
os.system("your command here")
# or
os.system('sh file.sh')
```

This command will run the script once, to completion, and block until it exits.

Comment: Don't you have to import sys too?

Comment: No, you don't; try opening a Python shell and running this snippet

Comment: Hi Ankit. I need some help on this. Assume the example.sh file is in Oracle cloud infrastructure. How can call/run such example.sh file in python? I need to connect to the oracle cloud then, I should use the script you written here. Could you please write the additional code (how to connect an example.sh file which in in OCI)? Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

If your shell script file does not have execute permissions, do so in the following way.

```py
import subprocess
subprocess.run(['/bin/bash', './test.sh'])
```

Answer (score 3):

Subprocess is good but some people may like [scriptine](http://packages.python.org/scriptine/index.html) better. Scriptine has more high-level set of methods like [shell.call(args)](http://packages.python.org/scriptine/modules/shell.html#scriptine.shell.call), [path.rename(new_name)](http://packages.python.org/scriptine/modules/path.html#scriptine.path.rename) and [path.move(src,dst)](http://packages.python.org/scriptine/modules/path.html#scriptine.path.move). Scriptine is based on [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) and others.

Two drawbacks of scriptine:

- Current documentation level would be more comprehensive even though it is sufficient.
- Unlike subprocess, scriptine package is currently not installed by default.

Answer (score 1):

Using @Manoj-Govindan answer, I found that I could run simple shell scripts from python, but the script I was desperately trying to run would fail with the error

```
Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

I changed the first argument from 'sh' to 'bash', and viola! Suddenly it executed.

```
subprocess.call(['bash', './test.sh'])
```

Comment: I guess you meant: voilà ;-)

Answer (score 0):

In order to run shell script in python script and to run it from particular path in ubuntu, use below ;

```
import subprocess

a= subprocess.call(['./dnstest.sh'], cwd = "/home/test") 

print(a)
```

Where CWD is current working directory

Below will not work in Ubuntu ; here we need to remove 'sh'

```
subprocess.call(['sh' ,'./dnstest.sh'], cwd = "/home/test")
```

Answer (score -11):

Please Try the following codes :

```
Import Execute 

Execute("zbx_control.sh")
```