# Translation of Shell Script in to Python

Tags: python, shell

I want to write a python code to run the job of the following Shell script for me:

```
for run in {1..100}
do
/home/Example.R
done
```

The shell script is basically running an R script for 100 times. Since I am new to python can somebody help me to write this code in python?

Comment: You can call shell script directly from python, look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777301/how-to-call-a-shell-script-from-python-code) thread for more info.

Comment: @Elias you are right but I want to learn how can I run that R script directly from python without running this Shell script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use python's `commands` module to execute external commands and capture their output.
The module has a function `commands.getstatusoutput(cmd)`, where `cmd` is the command you are looking to run, as a string.

Something like this could do the trick:

```
import commands
for x in xrange(100):
  commands.getstatusoutput("/home/Example.R")
```

Each iteration of the for loop, the `commands.getstatusoutput()` function will even return a tuple `(status, output)`, where status is the status after executing the program, and output being anything that the command would have written to stdout.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You could use subprocess.call to make an external command:

```
from subprocess import call

for i in xrange(100):
  call(["/home/Example.R"])
```