# Execute source linux command from python

Tags: python, linux, terminal, raspberry-pi3

How I can execute linux command **source reloader.sh** in python ?

**reloader.sh** have the following code:

```
#!bin/bash
source ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: you mean bash reloader.sh? instead of source reloader.sh?

Comment: Duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777301/how-to-call-a-shell-script-from-python-code

Comment: bash reloader.sh did not execute the commands in this script. So as far as I know only source can.

Comment: @TT methods in that post did not work. I think because of the nature of source command.

Comment: You could refer to the following https://superuser.com/questions/46139/what-does-source-do

Comment: Thanks for the referral but it still did not help me to find the right approach to execute source form *python*

Comment: try os.system("source reloader.sh ")

Comment: @repzero It shows error message........ sh: 1: source: not found