# Run bash script with Django

Tags: python, html, django, bash, shell

I'm really new in django. I need to run a bash script when I push a button in html, and I need to do it with Django Framework, because I used it to build my web. I'd be grateful if anybody could help me

Edit: I have added my template and my views for being more helpful. In the 'nuevaCancion' template, I use 2 views.

```html
<body>
 
 {% block cabecera %}
 <br><br><br>
 <center>
 <h2> <kbd>Nueva Cancion</kbd> </h2>
 </center>
 {% endblock %}
 
 {% block contenido %}

  <br><br>
  <div class="container">
      <form id='formulario' method='post' {% if formulario.is_multipart %} enctype="multipart/form-data" {% endif %} action=''>
    {% csrf_token %}
       <center>
    <table>{{formulario}}</table>
          <br><br>
          <p><input type='submit' class="btn btn-success btn-lg" value='Añadir'/>
     <a href="/ListadoCanciones/" type="input" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg">Cancelar</a></p>
    </center>
       </form>
     <br>
 </div>
 <center>
  <form action="" method="POST">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg">Call</button>
  </form>
 </center>
 {% endblock %}

</body>
```

Views.py

```
def index(request):
    if request.POST:
    subprocess.call('/home/josema/parser.sh')

    return render(request,'nuevaCancion.html',{})
```

parser.sh

```
#! /bin/sh
python text4midiALLMilisecs.py tiger.mid
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256107/running-bash-commands-in-python

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can do this with empty `form`.

In your template make a empty `form`

```
# index.html
<form action="{% url 'run_sh' %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button type="submit">Call</button>
</form>
```

Add `url` for your `form`

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^run-sh/$', views.index, name='run_sh')
]
```

Now in your `views.py` you need to call the `bash.sh` script from the `view` that returns your `template`

```
import subprocess

def index(request):
    if request.POST:
        # give the absolute path to your `text4midiAllMilisecs.py`
        # and for `tiger.mid`
        # subprocess.call(['python', '/path/to/text4midiALLMilisecs.py', '/path/to/tiger.mid'])

        subprocess.call('/home/user/test.sh')

    return render(request,'index.html',{})
```

My `test.sh` is in the home directory. Be sure that the first line of `bash.sh` have `sh executable` and also have right permission. You can give the permissions like this `chmod u+rx bash.sh`.

My `test.sh` example

```
#!/bin/sh
echo 'hello'
```

File permision `ls ~`

```
-rwxrw-r--   1 test test    10 Jul  4 19:54  hello.sh*
```

Comment: I'm trying what you say, but I think I'm missing something in my code because it doesn't work, where could I show my script and what I've done?   Also, do I have to add some url or it is not needed?

Comment: I have added them yet :)

Comment: you have two forms, and you say the you use two `views` function for one template, try to add new `url` and add this `url` to `form action`

Comment: i update my answer, i added the urls and add `action` to `form`

Comment: your `bash.sh` file contains only this line of code ? `python text4midiALLMilisecs.py tiger.mid` ?

Comment: Yes, It only has that line. text4allmilisecs.py is the file where I proccess some Code. Also I'd like to pasa tiger.mid like an argument, I mean, something generic so I can pass the file I would like. Sorry if my explanation is not as good as It should be

Comment: i update my answer, you can call directly `python text4midiALLMilisecs.py tiger.mid` in `subprocess` for this one you don't need `bash.sh` file

Comment: So I should put text4allMilisecs instead of test.sh un the view?

Comment: yes but put the full path to your `text4midiALLMilisecs.py` and full path for your `tiger.mid` for example if the files are in `/home/josema/text4midiALLMilisecs.py` and `/home/josema/tiger.mid` you need to use something like this `subprocess.call(['python', '/home/josema/text4midiALLMilisecs.py', '/home/josema/tiger.mid'])`

Comment: Thanks so much. I'll try It. I'll Mark as the right answer if It works when I try!

Comment: if you will do all right it will work, because i try it and it works

Comment: I'm disturbing again, sorry. I'm doing something wrong, because I import path in the urls.py, and I get the error that cannot import name path, but I followed everything you said me exactly.

Comment: what version of the django do you have?

Comment: I have the 1.11 version of django, and 2.7.12 version of python

Comment: Thank you so much! You saved me :)

Comment: Permission part was crucial to my problem, should have guessed it, but I'm quiet new to scripting so fully overlooked it. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use  python module **subprocess** in your view.

```
import subprocess

def your_view(request):

    subprocess.call('your_script.sh')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can refer my blog for detailed explanation >>

http://www.easyaslinux.com/tutorials/devops/how-to-run-execute-any-script-python-perl-ruby-bash-etc-from-django-views/

I would suggest you to use Popen method of Subprocess module. Your shell script can be executed as system command with Subprocess.

Here is a little help.

Your **views.py** should look like this.

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
from django.http import HttpResponse

def main_function(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
            command = ["bash","your_script_path.sh"]
            try:
                    process = Popen(command, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
                    output = process.stdout.read()
                    exitstatus = process.poll()
                    if (exitstatus==0):
                            result = {"status": "Success", "output":str(output)}
                    else:
                            result = {"status": "Failed", "output":str(output)}

            except Exception as e:
                    result =  {"status": "failed", "output":str(e)}

            html = "<html><body>Script status: %s \n Output: %s</body></html>" %(result['status'],result['output'])
            return HttpResponse(html)
```

In this example, stderr and stdout of the script is saved in variable '*output*', And exit code of the script is saved in variable '*exitstatus*'.

Configure your **urls.py** to call the view function "*main_function*".

```
url(r'^the_url_to_run_the_script$', main_function)
```

Now you can run the script by calling *http://server_url/the_url_to_run_the_script*

Answer (score 1):

Do it with Python:

With Subprocess:

```
import subprocess
proc = subprocess.Popen("ls -l", stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output, err = proc.communicate()
print output
```

Or with `os` module:

```
import os
os.system('ls -l')
```

Answer (score 0):

From **Python 3.5 onwards**, `subprocess.run()` is the recommended approach

As per the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module);

> The recommended approach to invoking subprocesses is to use the run()
> function for all use cases it can handle. For more advanced use cases,
> the underlying Popen interface can be used directly.
>
> The run() function was added in Python 3.5; if you need to retain
> compatibility with older versions, see the Older high-level API
> section.

As in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57077168/1526703) example,

```
import subprocess

def index(request):
    if request.POST:
        subprocess.run(['/home/josema/parser.sh'])

    return render(request,'nuevaCancion.html',{})
```