# Automate several BASH commands

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, shell, automation

Any “proper” way to automate with python for build scripts?

I want to have my script do something like this:

```
cd /somewhere
git pull
npm run build
make deploy
```

Everywhere on google I see: `os.system("xxx")` or `subprocess.call(...)`.

In BASH, the above is simple, but I wanna create a cli python app
to create all of that stuff for me.

Comment: you can make use of python libraries such as `os, shutils, psutils, subprocess`

Comment: Write to a .sh file, and execute it via [subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777301/how-to-call-a-shell-script-from-python-code).

Comment: or, you can use `os.system` to execute the command directly on Python. Import `os` and run `os.systems('ls')` to see results.

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann You will see my first comment speaks directly about `subprocess`, and frankly, I'm not sure as to why using `os.system` would be wrong in this situation. The `ls` command was just for him to see that he can execute bash commands on Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the spirit of do not reinvent the wheel, there are lots of way to automate builds with python, getting for free things like dependencies management.

One useful tool is [doit](http://pydoit.org/index.html).

To get an idea, this is a very simple example similar to your use case:

```
import os

MY_PRJ_ROOT='/home/myname/my_project_dir'

def task_cd():
    def cd_to_somewhere():
        os.chdir(MY_PRJ_ROOT)
    return {
        'actions': [cd_to_somewhere]
    }

def task_git_pull():
    """pull my git repo"""
    return {
        'actions': ['git pull'],
    }

def task_build_rust_app():
    """build by awesome rust app"""
    return {
        'actions': ['cargo build']
    }
```

supposing the above is a file named `dodo.py`, the default name for doit tasks, run it as:

```
> doit
```

### Others resources

Also worth noting (to my knowledge, they are not an exhaustive list of pythons automation tools):

[SCons - a software construction tool](https://github.com/SCons/scons)

[ShutIt - A versatile automation framework](https://github.com/ianmiell/shutit)

Answer (score 0):

`os.system` call the shell and send the command to the shell, so you can easily do it:

```
import os

cmd == """\
cd /somewhere
git pull
npm run build
make deploy
""""

os.system(cmd)
```

It is so easy. We tend to forget that `os.system` do no directly execute the commands, but it dispatch command to the shell. So we can use redirection and pipe.