# subprocess.Popen could not find bash file in the same directory

Tags: python, shell, subprocess

I'm trying to run a bash script from a Python script. Both this bash script and python script reside in the same directory. However, when I run the Python script, I get `No such file or directory` error.

My current directory

```
xxx@xxx:/home# ls
check.sh sc.py
```

Following is the code I'm trying to run, `sc.py`:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(["check.sh", "ABC"])
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
xxx@xx:/home# python3 sc.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sc.py", line 2, in <module>
    subprocess.Popen(["check.sh", "ABC"])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 729, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1364, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'check.sh': 'check.sh'
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to call a shell script from python code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777301/how-to-call-a-shell-script-from-python-code)

Comment: `check.sh` is not an executable.

Comment: @mkrieger1, I am wondering, does it have to be executable? I remember I have called a bash script without it being executable before.

Comment: It doesn't have to have its executable bit set if you run it like this `bash check.sh` but that is not how you are running it, you are just running it with `check.sh` which means 1) it must have its executable bit set and 2) it must be on your PATH.

Comment: I think you need to specify the directory, i.e. `./check.sh`. How else should `subprocess`, respectively the shell, know, where to find the file?

Comment: If you run a command just by its name, say `x`, then the file x must be executable, and it must reside in one of the directories mentioned in your PATH. This is fundamental for Linux/Unix, and I guess that Python's _subprocess_ either adheres to this convention, or executes a shell (POSIX shell) for doing the work, in which case the shell adheres to this convention.

Answer (score 0):

There is no file check.sh **in PATH**. If you want to find something in *current* working directory, find it there.

```
subprocess.Popen(["./check.sh", "ABC"])
```

If you want to find something in the *same* directory as python script, navigate to the same directory as the python script.

```
import subprocess
from pathlib import Path
subprocess.Popen([str(Path(__file__).parent / "check.sh"), "ABC"])
```

Comment: I have tried your approach `import subprocess
subprocess.Popen([str(Path(__file__).parent / "check.sh"), "ABC"])
`. Same error.

Comment: Did you try the first? Try adding `.absolute()`. And, also, execute the shell explicitly. The erro may come because the executable in shebang in the script does not exists. Did you read the linked question in the comment above?

Comment: @KamilCuk same error will be thrown if the shebang on the start of the check.sh is not pointing to valid interpreter.